# Data types storage

Tags: c, types

The following code prints `255`, but if I assigned `0255` to `x`, as in the second line, the code prints `173`!

Is there any explanation for this?

```
void main()
{
    unsigned long x = 255;
    /* unsigned long x = 0255;*/
    unsigned char *ptr = &x;
    printf("%u",*ptr);
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a number has a '0' in front of other digits, it's treated as an octal number. And 255 in octal is 173 in decimal.

Answer (score 3):

```
unsigned char x = 0255;
```

`0255` is considered an octal `int` literal. This works because you can assign `int` literals to chars, and octal `0255` is `(5*8^0)+(5*8^1)+(2*8^2) = 173` in decimal notation.

Visit [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) for more info on what the different forms of notational string literals are, but for quick reference:

```
unsigned char x = 0255; // Octal -> 173 in decimal
unsigned char x = 255; // Decimal -> 255 in decimal
unsigned char x = 0x2F // Hexadecimal -> 47 in decimal
```